# Unable to install Google App Engine Plugin (Eclipse 3.6)

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, gae-eclipse-plugin

I've followed [these instructions](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/install-from-zip.html) but I'm unable to install the GAE plugin on Eclipse 3.6 Helios.

Any ideas what could be wrong and how to fix it?

This is a clean install of Eclipse, the only added features are the *Eclipse Web Developer Tools* per instructions.

This is on Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by installing Eclipse *for Java **EE** Developers*

Answer (score 0):

Don't make it more complex than needed. Use the PlugIn: [GAE Plugin Instructions](http://code.google.com/eclipse/docs/getting_started.html)

Answer (score 0):

The version for different types of eclipse is different for Google App Engine Plugin. Try to use different version of plugin as required by your eclipse . I Have used http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.4  for my Hellios Version eclipse and it is working file after installation . Do not forgot to researt your eclipse in clean mode after installation of plugin.